# variable sized harpoon delimiter

Tags: arrows, delimiters

I would like to have a variable sized delimiter version of
the ams symbols `\downharpoonleft`, `\downharpoonright` and `\upharpoonleft`, `\upharpoonright` respectively, such that they work with `\left` and `\right`.
Is there any package that provides something like that?

[image: Excerpt from symbols-a4.pdf]

Comment: if you can give sample contexts of what you'd like to have delimited, i may be able to concoct something.

Comment: 1. simple variable names and
2. matrices,
however other things might come.

Comment: Have you tried using `tikz`? The path decorations allow for all kind of "arrow-like" symbols in various lengths.

Comment: I use tikz a lot, however, I was hoping that there is some predefined way to do it. I could achieve what I want with tikz directly, but I would not know, how to make some generic variable-sized delimiters that work with `\left` and `\right` (which is what I want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Recipe for supporting `\left` and `\right`

`\left` and `\right` are supported by properties of `TFM` files. The symbol can be given in different sizes and build a list of characters with ascending sizes in the `TFM` file. The last entry in the list is an extensible character. The latter is shortly explained the documentation of `tftopl`, § 14:

> 14. Extensible characters are specified by an `extensible_recipe`, which  consists of four bytes called `top`, `mid`, `bot`, and `rep`
>   (in this order). These bytes are the character codes of individual
>   pieces used to build up a large symbol. If `top`, `mid`, or `bot` are
>   zero, they are not present in the built-up result. For example, an
>   extensible vertical line is like an extensible bracket, except that
>   the top and bottom pieces are missing.

The recipe for creating support for `\left` and `\right`:

1. Some real font (Type 1, …) is necessary that contains the characters and especially the pieces that are needed to build an extensible character. The programs
   `t1disasm` and `t1asm` might help in this task by learning from existing fonts.
2. The `TFM` file is created with the right data structures that references the font of the previous step. The programs `tftopl` and `pltotf` help in converting `TFM` files to a readable format and converting back. The documentation of `tftopl` also contains the description of the `TFM` file format with its data structures.
3. Definition of the new math font and its symbols in TeX/LaTeX.

This recipe is intended for the more experienced who has enough time (hours if not days).

### Poor man's solution via `\resizebox`

In the following I have hacked a example file that uses `\resizebox` of package `graphics` (or `graphicx`). The disadvantage is that also the line width is proportionately scaled, but this is too much for large sizes.

The hack tries to take into account:

- Delimiters are centered at the math axis.
- Support for the automatically resizing in subscripts, … (via `\mathpalette`).
- The bounding box for the harpoons have horizontal white space of the other side of the hook. For larger sizes it is scaled too much. Therefore the white space is first stripped
  and then reinserted as thin space for non-script styles and as half thin space in script styles.
- …

The example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\scaleddelims}[3]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \mathpalette{\@scaleddelims{#1}{#2}}{#3}%
  }%
}   
\newcommand*{\@scaleddelims}[4]{%
  % #1: left delimiter
  % #2: right delimiter
  % #3: \displaystyle, \textstyle, ...
  % #4: inner formula
  \begingroup
    #3%
    \sbox0{$\m@th#3\vphantom{A}#4$}%
    \setbox2\vbox{\hbox{$\m@th#3#1$}\kern\z@}%
    \setbox4\vbox{\hbox{$\m@th#3#2$}\kern\z@}%
    \setbox6\hbox{$#3\vcenter{}$}%
    \ifx\downharpoonleft#1\relax  
      \let\DelimLeft=L%
    \else\ifx\upharpoonleft#1%
      \let\DelimLeft=L%
    \else\ifx\downharpoonright#1%
      \let\DelimLeft=R%
    \else\ifx\upharpoonright#1%
      \let\DelimLeft=R%
    \fi\fi\fi\fi
    \ifx\downharpoonleft#2\relax
      \let\DelimRight=L%
    \else\ifx\upharpoonleft#2\relax
      \let\DelimRight=L%
    \else\ifx\downharpoonright#2\relax
      \let\DelimRight=R%
    \else\ifx\upharpoonright#2\relax
      \let\DelimRight=R%
    \fi\fi\fi\fi
    \ifx\DelimLeft L%
      \wd2=.6\wd2
    \fi
    \ifx\DelimRight L%
      \wd4=.6\wd4
    \fi
    \ifx\DelimLeft R%
      \sbox2{\kern-.4\wd2\box2}%
    \fi
    \ifx\DelimRight R%
      \sbox4{\kern-.4\wd4\box4}%
    \fi
    \dimen0=\ht0 %
    \advance\dimen0 by -\ht6 %
    \dimen2=\dp0 %
    \advance\dimen2 by \ht6 %
    \ifdim\dimen2>\dimen0 %  
      \dimen0=\dimen2 %
    \else
      \dimen0=\dimen0 %
    \fi
    \dimen2=\ht6 %
    \advance\dimen2 by -\dimen0 %
    \dimen0=2\dimen0 %
    \def\DelimCorr{%  
      \mskip.5\thinmuskip
      \nonscript\mskip.5\thinmuskip
    }%
    \mathopen{%
      \ifx\DelimLeft R\DelimCorr\fi
      \raisebox{\dimen2}{\resizebox{!}{\dimen0}{\box2}}%
      \ifx\DelimLeft L\DelimCorr\fi
    }%
    \begingroup
      #3#4%
    \endgroup
    \mathclose{%
      \ifx\DelimRight R\DelimCorr\fi
      \raisebox{\dimen2}{\resizebox{!}{\dimen0}{\box4}}%
      \ifx\DelimRight L\DelimCorr\fi
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$ x + \scaleddelims{\downharpoonleft}{\downharpoonright}{\frac{4x}{x^2+3}}
  + \scaleddelims\downharpoonleft\downharpoonright{\frac\cdot{\frac XY}}  
  + \scaleddelims\downharpoonleft\downharpoonright{\frac{\frac XY}\cdot}  
$

\bigskip
$ x + \left\rfloor \frac{4x}{x^2+3} \right\lfloor
  + \left\rfloor \frac\cdot{\frac XY} \right\lfloor
  + \left\rfloor \frac{\frac XY}\cdot \right\lfloor
$

\bigskip
$ \mathopen{\downharpoonleft} x \mathclose{\downharpoonright} =
  \scaleddelims{\downharpoonleft}{\downharpoonright}{x} =
  \rfloor x \lfloor
  \qquad
  \scaleddelims\downharpoonleft\downharpoonright{}
$

\bigskip
$ y \scaleddelims\downharpoonright\downharpoonleft{\frac ab} z
  ^{\scaleddelims\downharpoonleft\downharpoonright{c}}
$

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result of example file]

Comment: Thanks, however I'am new to this and haven't done any of it before. I'll try reading into it, any tutorial recommendation?

Comment: I would like to use this to define a restriction operator, like `\newcommand{\rest}[2]\scaleddelims{\upharpoonright}{\vphantom{.}}{\vphantom{#1}#2}`, but LaTeX tells me that either I'm missing a dollar sign or a `\begin{document}`. What should I do?

Comment: @jdc: A formal correct definition would be `\newcommand{\rest}[2]{\scaleddelims{\upharpoonright}{\vphantom{.}}{\vphantom{#1}#2}}`. But I have no idea, what `\rest` is supposed to do.

Comment: Wow, that was a dumb error. I somehow couldn't figure out the braces were missing. Also, I realize I wanted to put a `#1` before `\scaleddelims`. The goal was to denote the restriction of a function to a subdomain with a properly tall restriction sign. Thanks!

Comment: Another question, since I've got your attention: you seem to be saying `\upharpoonright` is already extensible, but I seem to get errors when putting, e.g., `\big` or `\left` before it. What else should I be doing?

Comment: @jdc: In contrary, the answer uses `\downharpoon...` as example for `\scaleddelims`. The `\upharpoon...` symbols are alike.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, what did you mean, then, by "The last entry in the list is an extensible character"?

Comment: @jdc: A character that is constructed from different parts and can therefore grow. The next quoted paragraph shortly explains, how this is done. Still all is defined via the TFM file format.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, I think I misunderstood. I thought that you meant that the character `\upharpoonarrow`, being the last entry in the list that the original poster provided, was itself an extensible character. It seems now that in "last entry in the list" you were referring to a different list. I apologize for the confusion.